# Autofac cannot be found in release pipeline

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a program `MyProgram.csproj` (which happens to be a .NET Core console app) and I am copying it's build (`bin\netcoreapp2.2`) into the release pipeline and trying to run it `MyProgram.dll` through Powershell as a task.

When I do so I get the error

```
2019-08-14T01:35:58.1153997Z     An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyProgram.deps.json) was not found:
2019-08-14T01:35:58.1154837Z     package: 'Autofac', version: '4.2.1'
2019-08-14T01:35:58.1155904Z     path: 'lib/netstandard1.1/Autofac.dll'
```

The reference is

```
  "Autofac/4.2.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.ComponentModel": "4.0.1"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "lib/netstandard1.1/Autofac.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "4.2.1.0",
        "fileVersion": "4.2.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
```

Any way I can get more information about why this assembly cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following to my .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and try updating all the references on the project

Answer (score 0):

The better way to get rid of dependency chaos is to deploy a self-contained publish, so that includes .NET Core libraries, the .NET Core runtime and referenced package dependencies.
Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) link, you can determine the runtime identifier (e.g. win-x64) and the configuration settings for release or debug builds.

```
dotnet publish .\MyProgram.csproj -c Release -r "win-x64" --self-contained -o .\publish
```

You can either use the *dotnet* extension in the build definition or add a powershell inline command to run the mention codes.

## YAML Example

```
resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: DefaultAgentPool
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config

- powershell: |
   # Write your powershell commands here.
   
   Write-Host "Starting dotnet cli publish command ..."
   dotnet publish --runtime "win-x64" -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -c Release --self-contained

  workingDirectory: src/Project
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: win'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: win-publish
```

This makes you sure that you're not going to get any dependency error in the specified runtime platform.